# Get a single row from multiple rows of a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as given below. Here, some data is also added.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationState](
            [ID] [varchar](8) NULL,
            [State] [int] NULL,
            [subState] [int] NULL,
            [SL] [int] NULL,
            [CanView] [bit] NULL,
            [CanEdit] [bit] NULL,
            [CanSave] [bit] NULL,
            [CanApproved] [bit] NULL,
            [CanReject] [bit] NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO
        SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
        GO
        INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationState] ([ID], [State], [subState], [SL], [CanView], [CanEdit], [CanSave], [CanApproved], [CanReject]) VALUES (N'00000001', 5, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationState] ([ID], [State], [subState], [SL], [CanView], [CanEdit], [CanSave], [CanApproved], [CanReject]) VALUES (N'00000001', 5, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)
        INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationState] ([ID], [State], [subState], [SL], [CanView], [CanEdit], [CanSave], [CanApproved], [CanReject]) VALUES (N'00000001', 5, 4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationState] ([ID], [State], [subState], [SL], [CanView], [CanEdit], [CanSave], [CanApproved], [CanReject]) VALUES (N'00000001', 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Need an optimized query (only show one row) to get the below result:

```
ID  | State | CanView | CanEdit | CanSave | CanApproved | CanReject    
1   |  5    |     1   |    1    |    1    |      1      |     1
```

Comment: What is the logic? For example, why should `CanReject` be 1 instead of 0?

Comment: if any row has 1 then it's column value will be 1 for Same ID and State

Comment: What about `subState` where the values are 2,3,4,2 but you are returning 1?

Comment: subState column will not be considered as selected column. Only mentioned column will be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it appears this is what you are looking for. You will need to better clarify your requirements if this does not meet the need.

Edit: If your goal is to group by ID and State, as Ivan mentioned, then do this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    State,
    MAX(CAST(CanView AS INT)) AS CanView,
    MAX(CAST(CanEdit AS INT)) AS CanEdit,
    MAX(CAST(CanSave AS INT)) AS CanSave,
    MAX(CAST(CanApproved AS INT)) AS CanApproved,
    MAX(CAST(CanReject AS INT)) AS CanReject
FROM
    dbo.ApplicationState
GROUP BY
    ID,
    State;
```

Comment: looks like his goal is to group by ID and State

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Maybe I read this wrong then?: "if any row has 1 then it's column value will be 1 for Same ID and State"

Comment: "Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator". If we cast bit value to integer then this query will be served my purpose. @Nicarus

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input and require output, I think you want any value  more  than  zero  ,consider  output 1.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    State,
    Case when  MAX(CanView) > 1 then 1 else 0 end AS CanView,
    Case when MAX(CanEdit) > then 1 else0 end AS CanEdit,
    MAX(CanSave) AS CanSave,
    MAX(CanApproved) AS CanApproved,
    MAX(CanReject) AS CanReject
FROM
    dbo.ApplicationState
GROUP BY
    ID,
    State;
```

Same you can do for  other column

Comment: Those `Can*` fields are bits, so they will only ever be `0`,`1`, or `NULL`. Therefore there is no need for the case logic and `MAX()` will not work on a `BIT` field.